# C# xmlReader simple XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I've got simple XML like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ftp>
    <address>ftp://ftp.example.com/</address>
    <user>jondoe</user>
    <password>Password123</password>
</ftp>
```

And I wanted to use this C# code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("address");
    string ftpAddress = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    reader.ReadToFollowing("user");
    string ftpUser = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    reader.ReadToFollowing("password");
    string ftpPw = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

It's working fine when I want to read only one content, like address but it fails when I want to read more/next ones. I thought this would be logical but it seems like it's not. How to read that XML and all elements of it: address, user and password? I would like to use XmlReader for that.

Comment: Have you considered creating a basic view model, then deserialize the xml to your view model?

Comment: I just want a simple method to read that XML. Nothing extensive like building view model for XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form I can think of would be this one:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(xmlPath));
var ftpAddress = xml.Element("address").Value;
var ftpUser = xml.Element("user").Value;
var ftpPwd = xml.Element("user").Value;
```

Of course you should add some safety by checking for null values and if the file exists..

**Update:**

I would implement a failsafe version this way:

```
if (!File.Exists(xmlPath))
    throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The FTP configuration file {0} is missing", xmlPath));

XElement xml = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(xmlPath));
var ftpAddress = GetConfigValue(xml, "address");
var ftpUser = GetConfigValue(xml, "user");
var ftpPwd = GetConfigValue(xml, "password");
```

With GetConfigValue like this:

```
private static string GetConfigValue(XContainer parent, XName name)
{
    var element = parent.Element(name);

    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid configuration file, missing element {0}", name));

    return element.Value;
}
```

Comment: thank you. It's working pretty well. And could you please tell me how you would do those safety checks the simple/elegant way?

Comment: Thank you Denis Thomas, that is all I need!